# Input multiple string values and convert 1 to float

Tags: python, type-conversion

In the following code:

```
a, b, c = input("A, B, C: ").split()

float(a)

print(a)
```

`a` should be a `float`, `b` is a string and `c` is an integer. Now if I try to convert a from a string to a `float` number, e.g. 0.9, I get this message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '0.9,'
```

What am I doing wrong? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Try casting it within the print statement, so `print(float(a))`

Comment: How would an input look like? Will the string get entered with quotes? And can it contain commas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is like @cosinepenguin said, you need to save the result of the conversion in other variable.

The second thing is that `str.split` method splits the input in words using space as separator. Given the "A, B, C: " string you are putting in the input function you may want to give the values as "0.9, foo, 8". If so you should use comma as the separator:

```
a, b, c = input("A, B, C: ").split(",")
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like what you're doing is putting commas between the values on the command line, e.g.:

```
0.9, text, 10
```

Here you will end up with "0.9," in variable a, not the "0.9" you expect.

So, you need to enter this on the command line instead:

```
0.9 text 10
```

Comment: Oh! You are right! But how can I enter a b and c with commas and still get a as a float?

Comment: @LeviAckerman you can use rstrip to remove trailing commas `float(a.rstrip(','))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to feed `split` your separator string; it defaults to a space, but your data has a space-comma.

```
a, b, c = input("A, B, C: ").split(", ")
```